# iPhone Pull Down Refresh like Tweetie - LIGHT VERSION

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I know there is stuff on GithHub which lets you implement a sleek 'pull down to sync' if you are in an UITableView.

However, all I would need to do is to know if the UITableView has been pulled down. I know there is a `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` function, but that does not appear to fire if I scroll in an UITableView.

All I would need to know is, I suppose, if the UITableView scrolled beyond the upper bonds (which would give a minus figure, I suppose).

I'd be very grateful if anyone has any suggestions / solutions to this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say if your UITableView is being managed by a UITableViewController or you are managing it yourself. UITableView will send `scrollViewDidScroll:` messages, but only to the delegate of the table view instance.

Since you're saying `scrollViewDidScroll:` is not firing, I assume you are not subclassing `UITableViewController` and doing something else. Add the method to your table view's delegate and you will be notified of the scroll position changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend `EGORefreshTableHeaderView`. Available on GitHub and works great.